# Select data from MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables called `table_one` and `table_two`, with the following properties:

- Both of them have one common column called `column_id`.
- The values of `table_one.column_id` are unique, whereas the values of `table_two.column_id` are not.
- `table_two` has two extra columns called `ts_one` and `ts_two`. `ts_one` is not null, but `ts_two` may be null.  Only one row per `table_two.column_id` permits the `ts_two` value to be null.
- Not all values from `table_one.column_id` may be presented in `table_two.column_id`.

For example:

```
table_one
column_id
1
2
3
4
5


table_two
column_id    ts_one        ts_two
2            2014-10-01    null
3            2014-10-02    2014-10-03
3            2014-10-05    null
4            2014-10-01    2014-10-05
```

I need to get all id from `table_one.column_id`, where:

1. id in `table_one.column_id` and not in table_two.column_id(1, 5 satisfy that)
2. id in `table_one.column_id` and in `table_two.column_id` where `ts_two` is not null and there is no another rows with same id where `ts_two` with null value - (only 4 satisfy).

Both conditions should be taken into account. The results should include 1, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single join and an aggregate...

```
SELECT t1.column_id FROM table_one AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT column_id, (COUNT(column_id) = COUNT(ts_two)) as no_nulls FROM table_two
    GROUP BY column_id
) AS t2
ON t1.column_id = t2.column_id
WHERE t2.column_id IS NULL OR (t2.column_id IS NOT NULL AND t2.no_nulls = TRUE)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14855/8/0

1. Query everything from table 1
2. Query each id from table 2, along with whether it has any null ts_two entries for that id.
3. Joins them together if 1 is missing from 2, or if 1 is in 2 and has no null ts_two entries.

Answer (score 0):

for your first question "    id in table_one.column_id and not in table_two.column_id(1, 5)
"

this query should do

```
SELECT column_id 
FROM table_one AS o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_two WHERE column_id = o.column_id)
```

for your second question "id in table_one.column_id and in table_two.column_id where ts_two is not null and there is no id with a null value - (only 4)"

this query should also do

```
SELECT t.* FROM table_two AS t 
INNER JOIN table_one AS o ON o.column_id = t.column_id
WHERE t.ts_two IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_two WHERE ts_two IS NULL AND column_id = o.column_id)
```

the question is so confusing. but from the comments below this should give you what you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT  column_id
FROM (
SELECT column_id 
FROM table_one AS o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_two WHERE column_id = o.column_id)
UNION
SELECT t.column_id FROM table_two AS t 
INNER JOIN table_one AS o ON o.column_id = t.column_id
WHERE t.ts_two IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_two WHERE ts_two IS NULL AND column_id = o.column_id)
  ) AS t
```

Comment: Both conditions should be taken into account at the same time. result should include 1, 4 and 5

Comment: Put an `UNION` and a `DISTINCT t.column_id` on the second query: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dfe7/3)

Comment: then can you list the final results please?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b39d2/15/0

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_one A
LEFT JOIN Table_Two B
 on A.Column_ID = B.ColumN_ID
LEFT JOIN (Select column_ID 
           From table_two 
           where ts_one is null or ts_two is null) C
  ON A.ColumN_Id = C.Column_ID
WHERE C.Column_ID is null
OR B.Column_ID is Null;
```

What this does:

- Returns all data from table 1 in Set 1
- Joins to data from table two which are not in 1,5 (Adds data to set 1)
- Joins to data from table two that has been filtered to only include records with nulls (creates a 2nd set)
- Excludes records where matches exist in 2nd join to table two. (Filters data so that only data in first set and not in second set is returned.

Comment: you hardcoded (1,5) but there are could be more values

Comment: Simple enough pulled it out and added where clause where B.column_Id is null.

Comment: this one looks right. I will do more tests and then can accept it. thanks